# Roof Ridge Venting - When in 2012 did roof venting become required instead of standard roofing codes?

Tags: roof

In what month of 2012 did roof ridge vents become code, as opposed to standard roofing when roof ridge venting was not a requirement? I ask because I need to present as evidence to the BBB (Better Business Bureau).

Comment: In what state do you reside?

Comment: Code changes almost always begin on January  1  are you asking about international residential code? Some state code? Or the NRCA codes. (National roofing contractors association)? Or some random local county or municipal code?

Comment: Who is your AHJ, and what Code are you discussing here?

Answer (score 2):

Each state “adopts” the new Building Code after it has been reviewed, changes made, and approved by the State Building Codes Office. Adoption occurs on October 1, (start of the new fiscal year/budget,) with amendments adopted throughout the year.

Little known fact is that the Code is divided into two parts: 1) construction, additions, etc., and 2) maintenance.

You don’t need a Permit for “maintenance”, (I.e.: painting, carpet replacement, etc.) Re-roofing is often placed in the “maintenance” category. Each jurisdiction makes their own determination regarding re-roofing.

However, roofing (initial installation) is usually in the construction category and needs a permit.